# Cannot get method get of undefined node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm writing a new kind of structure and scalability for an express application.

**Issue:**

I don't like to define each route on app.js file.

**Solution:**

Make something automated in order to load the routes automatically.

So far, I have this code on index.js (routes folder) file:

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(app) {
  recursive_require(__dirname, app);

  function recursive_require(directory, app) {
    fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach(function(file) {
      if (fs.lstatSync(directory + '/' + file + '/').isDirectory()) {
        var has_no_js_files = false;
        directory = directory + '/' + file + '/'; 

        console.log('Scanning recursively on ' + directory);

        // We run across the directory to check if there are any js files.
        fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach(function(file) {
          console.log('Reading file/directory ' + file);
          if (file.match(/\.js$/g)) {
            has_no_js_files = true;
            console.log('Found js files on directory ' + directory);
          }
        });

        // If the folder has no js files, we take in mind that there are other folders inside
        // so we scan the folder recursively.
        if (!has_no_js_files) {
          console.log('No JS files found on ' + directory + ' going to scan recursively');
          recursive_require(directory.substr(0, directory.lastIndexOf('/')));
        } else {
          // Otherwise, we require the directory taking in mind that we have just js files.
          console.log('Found JS files on ' + directory + ', require them');
          require(directory)(app);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now, This seems to work but I have a bit of an issue..

My idea is to have everything on folders, so say, this structure:

```
routes
  admin
    posts
      index.js <- handles add, remove, edit for posts
    users
      index.js <- handles add, remove, edit for users
  blog
    posts
      index.js <- handles show for frontend
  index.js <- Loads all of the files recursively.
```

Now, I have a bit of an issue with this code...

I'm having this error:

```
PS C:\Users\bony-_000\Documents\GitHub\node-blog> node app
Scanning recursively on C:\Users\bony-_000\Documents\GitHub\node-blog\routes/admin/
Reading file/directory posts
No JS files found on C:\Users\bony-_000\Documents\GitHub\node-blog\routes/admin/ going to scan recursively
Scanning recursively on C:\Users\bony-_000\Documents\GitHub\node-blog\routes/admin/posts/
Reading file/directory index.js
Found js files on directory C:\Users\bony-_000\Documents\GitHub\node-blog\routes/admin/posts/
Found JS files on C:\Users\bony-_000\Documents\GitHub\node-blog\routes/admin/posts/, require them

C:\Users\bony-_000\Documents\GitHub\node-blog\routes\admin\posts\index.js:2
  app.get('/admin/posts/add', function(req, res) {
      ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
```

Though I'm sending the app var...

Any help will be much appreciated, also, feel free to use the code.

Comment: Try changing `recursive_require(directory.substr(0, directory.lastIndexOf('/')));` to `recursive_require(directory.substr(0, directory.lastIndexOf('/')), app);`

Comment: Holy!, can't believe that was my error...

Thanks a bunch! :), now I'm facing another error but I'm going to look at it on my own, you rock!

Comment: oh, already fixed :), i remove post

Comment: Yup, now there's another error, seems that the folders need to have an index.js, so I'll have to require it somehow without changing the logic much, I've something in mind already :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved all the issues and now I have my structured MVC Online!

This is the code for anyone to use:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    required_files = [];


module.exports = function(app) {
  recursive_require(__dirname, __dirname, app);

  function recursive_require(directory, base_dir, app) {
    fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach(function (input) {
      var next_directory = directory + '/' + input + '/';
      // If we are on the base dir, we ignore the index.js file
      if (!(required_files.indexOf(base_dir + '/index') > -1)) {
        required_files.push(base_dir + '/index');  
      }

      // Check if it's a directory
      if (fs.lstatSync(next_directory).isDirectory()) {
        // We require it recursively
        console.log('Reading directory ' + next_directory);
        recursive_require(next_directory.substr(0, next_directory.lastIndexOf('/')), base_dir, app);
      } else {
        // We require all (except the index.js file if the var is set to true) js files on folder
        require_files(directory, app);
        return;
      }
    });
  }

  function require_files(directory, app) {
    fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files) {
      files.forEach(function(file) {
        if (file.match(/\.js$/g)) {
          var file_path = directory + '/' + file;
          file_path = file_path.substr(0, file_path.indexOf('.js'));
          if (required_files.indexOf(file_path) == -1) {
            required_files.push(file_path);
            require(file_path)(app);
          }
        }
      });
    });
    return;
  }
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.